# Memory leak detection in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, memory, memory-leaks

My asp.net website grows to 2 GB in 20 minutes and restarts.
When I run this website throw Visual Studio on localhost and update one page 30 times website grows by ~50-100 MB.
I have tried to run very simple page without database connection and layout. On this page was only one word. And after several hundreds updates of this page website was not growing.
Then I have tried return to first (complex) page, but I have commented all markup in cshtml file. Only Layout was on this page. Website was grows 
insignificantly.
Then I have commented layout and leave only simple table markup with many injected data. After 30 updates website grows by ~50-100 MB again.

I have tried to use dotMemory for detection the reason. Some screenshots from it: 
[image: used memory]
[image: largest size]
[image: memory structure]
[image: heap fragmentation]
[image: new objects]

Tell me if I can give you more information.

Fragmentation of Generation 2 is 97%. (138 MB used, 220 free). I don't know how must it be.

I have take 2 snapshots. Most of new objects (and new bytes) are Char[], which part of StringBulder, which part of PageExecutionContext, which part of CacheEntry.

I think, it is some cache of view (cshtml files). But it is only a guess.

Can any help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide some technical details. We cannot help you without that.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, I'm ready to give you more details, but I don't know what details you need.

Comment: I need details like, which type of pages you have. As you written here that you don't use database, so just aspx pages? Or just html static pages? How many total pages? etc.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, I tested on only one page. This is cshtml file with many data from database. I have tried clear all markup but all database logic was left. In this case application's memory doesn't grow. Dispose() method of database context was called.

Comment: So it means that bec of data memory grows. One thing you can do, ask your hosting provider about it.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, sorry, but I don't  fully understand your comment. And this tests were on myself developing machine.

Comment: Oh Ok, I thought you have uploaded your application on any server. Anyways, if its about your machine, we need to check data which you are using. And that may be cause of increasing memory.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, this problem shown on any page of website (don't on only one page). And data is simple. It's just strings in table. If I can give you more details, tell me what you need.

Comment: Tell me what do you have on your page?

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, [screenshot from page](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33356150/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9.png). It's just table with string data.

Comment: Ok, It seems data only, it should not increase memory. Is there any other process running on your machine which causes memory issue?

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, no. Such behavior is on my machine and on producation server. I haven't another process wich can influence on website beside dotMemory or VisualStudio.

Comment: May be you can check your application on another machine. And verify what happen there.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, I have check it on another machine. Same behaviour. No difference.

Comment: Weird. Instead of your page, can you add test page with some content and try.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, what content must be on this test page? I tried put big static content (without Razor injections and without layout). In this case after 100 page refreshes application grows only by ~40 MB (within the error)

Comment: Try simple page with just hello world.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, with hello world page after 100 refreshes memory increased by ~26MB

Comment: Yeah so I think its obvious, may be it will be application pool's occupation.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, sorry, I don't understand, what is "pool's occupation"? My english is not good.

Comment: I mean any application runs under application pool. May be that's memory size of that. If its just 26MB its not much.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, no, there is only one application in this pool: my website.

Comment: True, but do you think 26MB is much?

Comment: No, it is not much. But 100-200 MB after 30 refreshings with full markup and data injections is much.

Comment: May be change your data and check, whether it is data related issue.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, I checked another page with another data. After 100 refreshings memory was increased by 351 MB.

Comment: Well, It should not happen usual, try with another version of visual studio and check.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, in my tests I run this application in Visual Studio 2015 Upd 2. I tried to install Visual Studio 2013 Upd 5 and run application in it, but C# 6 was used in this project, and application cann't run in VS 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was found answer. I used navigation property in EF as a collection with about 100 000 entities. And this entities was loaded from DB every second just for adding new entity to this collection.

Solution: don't use navigation property on so big collections. For adding entity use DbSet from DbContext.

Answer (score 0):

This is too late but here's my answer.

I had MVC 5.0 and had this very same problem. After upgrade to 5.2.3 it all went away and memory usage was back to normal.